# How to generate HTML reports for functional tests using Intern tool

Tags: intern

The [intern tutorial](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#reporter-results) doesn't provide how to generate HTML reports for function tests.

I would like to know the below things :

1. How to generate HTML report in Intern for functional tests.
2. If we can generate a Junit XML file. best tools to convert XML file to HTML and how to integrate with Intern.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in way to generate an HTML report for functional tests. Reporters are pretty easy to create, though, and it would be relatively straightforward to create an HTML reporter using the JUnit reporter as a basis. It would just need to be modified to emit an HTML doc header and HTML tags rather than JUnit XML tags. This would be more flexible than trying to convert a generated JUnit report to HTML since you would have total control of the output.